# Why does a "let" statement force an "applicative do" block into requiring a monad constraint?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc, applicative, do-notation

Consider this example:

```
{-# language ApplicativeDo #-}

module X where

data Tuple a b = Tuple a b deriving Show

instance Functor (Tuple a) where
    fmap f (Tuple x y) = Tuple x (f y)

instance Foldable (Tuple a) where
    foldr f z (Tuple _ y) = f y z

instance Traversable (Tuple a) where
    traverse f (Tuple x y) = do
        y' <- f y
        let t' = Tuple x y'
        return $ t'
```

Looks nice! But no:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling X                ( X.hs, interpreted )

X.hs:15:9: error:
    • Could not deduce (Monad f) arising from a do statement
      from the context: Applicative f
        bound by the type signature for:
                   traverse :: forall (f :: * -> *) a1 b.
                               Applicative f =>
                               (a1 -> f b) -> Tuple a a1 -> f (Tuple a b)
        at X.hs:14:5-12
      Possible fix:
        add (Monad f) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            traverse :: forall (f :: * -> *) a1 b.
                        Applicative f =>
                        (a1 -> f b) -> Tuple a a1 -> f (Tuple a b)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: y' <- f y
      In the expression:
        do y' <- f y
           let t' = Tuple x y'
           return $ t'
      In an equation for ‘traverse’:
          traverse f (Tuple x y)
            = do y' <- f y
                 let t' = ...
                 return $ t'
   |
15 |         y' <- f y
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Even this fails:

```
instance Traversable (Tuple a) where
    traverse f (Tuple x y) = do
        y' <- f y
        let unrelated = 1
        return $ Tuple x y'
```

So, introducing any `let` statement removes the *"applicative"* from the *"applicative do"*. Why?

Comment: Before reading the answers here, I thought this was because of the call to `return`. So, for future readers, I think it’s worthwhile noting that this still gives an error even when `pure` is used instead of `return`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would translate into

```
let unrelated = 1 in return $ Tuple x y'
```

which doesn't have the form `return <something>`, and applicative do [requires the last statement to be a `return` or `pure`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#applicative-do-notation):

> In general, the rule for when a do statement incurs a `Monad` constraint is as follows. If the do-expression has the following form:
>
> ```
> do p1 <- E1; ...; pn <- En; return E
> ```
>
> where none of the variables defined by `p1...pn` are mentioned in `E1...En`, and `p1...pn` are all variables or lazy patterns, then the expression will only require `Applicative`. Otherwise, the expression will require `Monad`. The block may return a pure expression `E` depending upon the results `p1...pn` with either `return` or `pure`.
>
> Note: the final statement must match one of these patterns exactly:
>
> ```
> return E
> return $ E
> pure E
> pure $ E
> ```
>
> otherwise GHC cannot recognise it as a return statement, and the transformation to use `<$>` that we saw above does not apply. In particular, slight variations such as `return . Just $ x` or `let x = e in return x` would not be recognised.

If you look at the description of desugaring in https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/applicative-do, it also doesn't support `let` in any way.

Answer (score 4):

What applicative expression would you like this to desugar to? A monadic expression is a series of chained scopes, so it makes sense for a `let` to introduce a binding that extends over all the remaining scopes, but with applicative the various expressions can't really depend on each other, so there's no scope that it makes sense to desugar the `let` into.

Comment: In principle, `do x1 <- e1; ... ; xn <- en ; let y = eY ; return eR` could desugar to `do x1 <- e1; ... ; xn <- en ; return (let y = eY in eR)` and from there to applicative notation (when possible). We could also do that for `let y=eY; xi <- ei` part, but we would need to require that `eY` does not use `x(i-1),...`. A lot of constraints on "what can be used where" would need to be required, which could be confusing. Hence, it does not look as a very convenient feature.

Comment: Isn't this the same as desugaring to a `let` around the entire `do` expression, since the variable being bound can't depend on any of the previous bindings, and can't be used by any following bindings?

Comment: I think so, except for the final `return`, where you can use the previous bindings.

Comment: @chi Actually when I was writing this example, I thought like, _duh, of course it should desugar into a `let ... in ...` expression_. I am still not sure why not.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov But what *specific* let/in expression? For the straw man of `unrelated`, of course you can put it anywhere, but that's not very interesting. For the version with `t'` there is no obvious let/in expression with the same meaning. The closest is `(\y' -> let t' = Tuple x y' in t') <$> f y`, which I guess seems reasonable for this simple case but doesn't generalize well, as chi explains.